# EntityFramework 5 returning same object instead of returning new objects

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-5

consider the following...

**DataBase:**

```
Table: XFUNCTION
-------------
|ID  |NAME  |
-------------
|1   |F1    |
-------------
|2   |F2    |
-------------

Table: XSYSTEM
-------------
|ID  |NAME  |
-------------
|3   |S1    |
-------------
|4   |S2    |
-------------

Table: FUNCTION_HAS_SYSTEM
--------------------------------
|ID  |SYSTEM_ID  |FUNCTION_ID  |
--------------------------------
|5   |3          |1            |
--------------------------------
|6   |3          |2            |
--------------------------------
|7   |4          |1            |
--------------------------------
|8   |4          |2            |
--------------------------------
```

**Code:**

```
var dbContext = new EFContext();

var functions = dbContext.XFUNCTION; //Count == 2

var systems = new List<XSYSTEM>();

foreach(var func in functions)
{
    foreach(var sys in func.systems) //Count == 2
    {
        if (!systems.Contains(sys))
                    systems.Add(sys);
    }
}

Assert.IsTrue(systems.Count == 4);
```

`Output: systems.Count == 2 not 4`

As long as I have not overwritten `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` I expected 4 systems not 2... **Can somebody tell me why EF does this, is it expected? And how can i prevent this behavior?**

The reason for this question was, that when I tried to manipulate the system objects in one of the functions, without doing a `SaveChange()`. The same thing happend to the system object in the other function. I know they are the same systems in the database but I expected them to be their own object and not be shared in the entities.

Comment: This seems right. You only have two systems, and they are equals. Even though you're accessing those systems from different functions, the system is still the same. If you want `systems.Count` of four, then why don't you use `FUNCTION_HAS_SYSTEM`?

Comment: The output looks right! Since there only 2 systems 3 & 4, the count will be 2. Though it appears in 4 rows in FUNCTION_HAS_SYSTEM, you are checking if (!systems.Contains(sys)) which will add the system only once to the list. Remove the IF condition if you want the count to be 4.

Comment: Object.Equals() returns true because EF returns the same object! EF keeps the queried entity in memory and reuses it by default unless you disable change tracking.

Comment: okay you have all clearly answered why this happens but not how to get around it. @Poornima if i removed the if, the list would contain 4 references to 2 objects, and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.Equals() returns true because EF returns the same object! EF keeps the queried entity in memory and reuses it by default unless you disable change tracking.

There are many ways to disable change tracking:

1) Use [.AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

```
var xfunctionSet = dbContext.XFUNCTION.AsNoTracking();
Assert.AreSame(xfunctionSet.First(), xfunctionSet.First()); //fails
```

2) Change the [MergeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx)

BUT if you are just going to count the total records in FUNCTION_HAS_SYSTEM, just do

```
dbContext.FUNCTION_HAS_SYSTEM.Count()
```

Comment: If I disable ChangeTracking how do I go about storing changes later on? I guess id have to refetch the object with the context, and manually set all its properties to the values of the not tracked object and then call `SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: You can attach the entity to the context. See _Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context_ in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx). This is something that I avoid doing as much as possible though because it can get complicated and inefficient.

Comment: My thought exactly. Im used to NHibernate, and I can't remember stumbling upon this problem with it.

Comment: Yup Hibernate and NHibernate don't have change tracking

Comment: And they require you to implement Object.Equals unlike EF

Comment: Yeah Iv been wondering if I had to override the equality members with EF also.